# Facing issues after renaming XCode project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, rename

According to this Tutorial I tried to rename my old XCode project. After running I'm facing the following issus:

```
<unknown>:0: error: error opening input file '/Users/MyName/Desktop/ProjectFolderWithNewProjectName/
OldProjectName/OldProjectName-Bridging-Header.h' (No such file or directory)
```

Once I tried some stuff with Header Bridge but as far as I know I deleted it. But obvious it isn't. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. I had to chang in Project directery the Bridging-Header titel from the OldName to the new name.